# Diff time in php not clear

Tags: php, time, diff

```
$ts=microtime(true);
myfucntion($params);
$te= microtime(true);
$diff = $te-$ts;
echo $diff; // outputs 3.0994415283203E-5
```

what does 3.0994415283203**E-5** means?  is it 3+ seconds

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php AND https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation

Answer (score 0):

That 'odd' number is the scientific notation.
You can use `number_format` to get a normal formatted number. Like:

```
$a = 3.0994415283203E-5;
echo number_format($a, 5);
```

Output:

```
0.00003
```

So actually, the number is far below 1 second ;) .

Answer (score 0):

3.0994415283203*E-5* is a very very small value then the 1.

Here E-5 means 10 to the power -5 (read as exponentiation -5 of 10). It is a mathematical term. You number 3.0994415283203E-5 means

> 3.0994415283203/100000 = 0.000030994415283203

Which is very small number then the 1 second. means less then 1 second.

> 1 microsecond = 0.000001 seconds

Your result is in seconds e.i 0.000030994415283203 seconds.